# How to hide a div with angular js ng-hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a page with a div which contains a jumbotron, this is the first page that is display anytime the site is accessed. On this page I have some links which link to different pages using the '$routeProvide'/angular. I want to hide the jumbotron from the other links/pages but I am not sure how to do that.

main page :

```
<body ng-app="single-page-app">
    <div ng-controller="cfgController">
        <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header col-md-12 col-sm-12 logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/gilgal.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Responsive image"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="container-fluid col-md-9 col-sm-12 hidden-xs col-md-offset-2">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#/advService">Advisory Service</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#/imService">Investment Service</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#/greService">Infrastructure Development</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron" ng-hide="hideme">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row jumb">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 head-card">
                    <h4 class="head-text">ADVISORY SERVICES</h4>
                    <p class="head-desc">We provide Corporate Finance Advisory Services for private and public institutions in Sub-Saharan Africa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 head-card">
                    <h4 class="head-text">INVESTMENT MANAGEMENT SERVICES</h4>
                    <p class="head-desc">We focus on Real Estate and Infrastructural Projects in Sub-Saharan Africa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div ng-view>

        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-md-12 foot">
            <p class="col-md-offset-1">All content copyright of Gilgal Capital Limited 2015 | Branding and Website by Ashebby</p>
        </div>
    <!-- Angular Route.js -->
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular.js -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
```

here is my script.js

```
var app=angular.module('single-page-app',['ngRoute']);


app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
          .when('/index',{
                templateUrl: 'index.html'
          })  
          .when('/about',{
                templateUrl: 'about.html'
          })
            .when('/advService',{
                templateUrl: 'advService.html'
          })
            .when('/imService',{
                templateUrl: 'imService.html'
          })
            .when('/greService',{
                templateUrl: 'greService.html'
          })
            .when('/contact',{
                templateUrl: 'contact.html'
          });


});
app.controller('cfgController'['$Scope', function($scope) {

$Scope.hideme = false;

$Scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    $scope.hideme = true;
});

}]);
```

here is a typical link to a different page about.html :

```
<div class="container-fluid col-md-12 about-us">
        <div class="about-us col-md-offset-1">
            <h2 class="col-md-10">
                <span class="title2">About Us</span>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </h2>
            <p class="col-md-10 article">text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first page having any route associated with it?

Comment: I didn't try but pearhaps on the idea , pearhaps you can add $route in the controller's scope so you know on which page you are and the do a test something like **$scope.hideme = $route.currentpage == '/index' ? true : false;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that really hard... So [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) is easy to use

To hide a div just do this :

```
 <div ng-hide="hideme">your content </div>
```

and in your controller you define hideme variable like this :

```
  $scope.hideme = true; // true to hide ,false to show
```

Edit:  So in your case  do this :

```
  <li class="navlink"><a ng-click="hideIt()" href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
```

In your controler make a fucntion hideIt to hide the jumbotron div :

```
   $scope.hideIt = function(){
     $scope.hideme = true;
     }
```

Comment: I understand that but I want to show jumbotron on main page and hide it on the other pages

Comment: What do you mean jubotron?

Comment: I don't get it if you only to hide the div with jumbotron class , just use ng-hide ? What's your problem

Comment: I want to hide the jumbotron from the about page not the main(index.html)

Comment: I will edit my post with the right solution give me minutes... (Look at the title of your question , next time put a right title)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

$rootScope.hideme = false;

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
    $rootScope.hideme = true;

});
```

Along with your code, just add this run block. It should work.

Comment: @Okazari - I agree with you, however, with respect to the code, I feel this is the only solution possible. In place of ng-init, though, I can move the code to its respective controller.

Comment: I tried this but now my links are not working, I have updated my code above.

Comment: @Okazari - Thanks for all the support and help :)

Comment: I have modified the code can you check above, the links aren't working at all @nikhil

Comment: It should not have have worked. Allow me some time. I will come with 100% working solution